# Re-deploy an older revision with AWS Code Deploy

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-code-deploy

In AWS Console of AWS Code Deploy, I can see the list of all deployed revisions of an application. It also allows me to re-deploy an older version by merely by clicking a button!

I want to do the same thing using CLI, so that to re-deploy a previous version of the application we can deploy just by knowing the revision ID rather than running a full push or create-deployment command.

Is there a way to run a command similar to "aws deploy push " ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do need create-deployment to deploy a revision. It's equivalent to pushing the "Deploy revision" button. Revisions are created by "push", and then will be used for deployments. Pushing a revision merely bundles your revision and create a new revision record in CodeDeploy.  It doesn't actually deploy anything from my understanding.  Take a look at the example at http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/deploy/push.html.  You will see the command for deploying a revision at the bottom of page.  My push command's output doesn't have a version, so I am not sure why there's one in that example and how it's used.

Comment: I noticed that whether you quote the eTag or not in create-deployment command, it always removes it.  That caused a different revision location than the one created by revision push, and resulted in a new revision created automatically.  However, running the same create-deployment won't create any additional revisions in the 2nd and subsequent runs.